# Why is Memcache not starting automatically?

Tags: centos, memcached, memcache

I installed memcache in my CentOS server, and the respective libraries for php as well:

[image]

Despite having installed both of them, I ended using Memcache

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
```

Since I wanted the memcache service to run automatically after rebooting the server, I did this:

```
memcached -d -u nobody -m 512 -p 11211 127.0.0.1
chkconfig memcached on
```

Then I checked:

```
chkconfig --list | grep memcache
> memcached 0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

After a few minutes of use:

```
echo stats | nc 127.0.0.1 11211

STAT pid 30412
STAT uptime 1616
STAT time 1424280050
STAT version 1.4.15
STAT libevent 1.4.13-stable
STAT pointer_size 64
STAT rusage_user 0.053991
STAT rusage_system 0.152976
STAT curr_connections 42
STAT total_connections 144
STAT connection_structures 43
STAT reserved_fds 20
STAT cmd_get 639
STAT cmd_set 360
STAT cmd_flush 0
STAT cmd_touch 0
STAT get_hits 262
STAT get_misses 377
STAT delete_misses 0
STAT delete_hits 0
STAT incr_misses 0
STAT incr_hits 0
STAT decr_misses 0
STAT decr_hits 0
STAT cas_misses 0
STAT cas_hits 0
STAT cas_badval 0
STAT touch_hits 0
STAT touch_misses 0
STAT auth_cmds 0
STAT auth_errors 0
STAT bytes_read 147954
STAT bytes_written 455620
STAT limit_maxbytes 536870912
STAT accepting_conns 1
STAT listen_disabled_num 0
STAT threads 4
STAT conn_yields 0
STAT hash_power_level 16
STAT hash_bytes 524288
STAT hash_is_expanding 0
STAT bytes 138385
STAT curr_items 359
STAT total_items 360
STAT expired_unfetched 0
STAT evicted_unfetched 0
STAT evictions 0
STAT reclaimed 1
END
```

Everything ran fine for a few weeks. After that time I decided to check the service status, and for some reason, memcache was not running at all. I had to put it back on (i did reboot the server at some point in those weeks):

```
memcached -d -u nobody -m 512 -p 11211 127.0.0.1
```

Why didn't memcache start automatically after the reboot? Isn't that what `chkconfig memcached on` is for? Why could it have stopped working?

Answer (score 1):

You should check what happens (logs etc) when you try to run

```
service memcached start
```

after stopping the manually started instance. If that doesn't help check the boot.log and next time you start the sytem check the logs as early as possible.

---

> > memcached 0:off     1:off     2:off     3:off     4:off     5:off     6:off

Memcached is not configured to auto start, it is set to off for all run-levels.

You should try to set it on again.

Comment: sorry, that was not the result of chkconfig --list | grep memcache, i just updated with the current result.

Answer (score 0):

## Why is Memcache not starting automatically?

I don't have the exact answer of 'why', but I have a solution for that issue as listed and described below;

Step 1) Create an **executable** file named

```
/usr/local/bin/memcached
```

and put below contents in that file;

```
#!/bin/sh

echo Checking for memcached instance...
result=$(pidof memcached)
echo "$result"
if [ -z "$result" ]; then
  echo memcached is not running. Attempt to start it...
  /usr/bin/memcached -u memcached -p 11211 -m 1024 -c 1024 -l localhost -d &
else
  echo memcached is already running. Do nothing.
fi

echo End of script.
```

Step 2) Put that script in **/etc/crontab**

```
* * * * root /usr/local/bin/memcached
```

That's all what I did. That script will be executed every minute and check for any running memcached instance.

Hope this help.

Comment: Maybe you should check out the `service` command sometime.